# Set the 'program' value in your launch config

Tags: dart, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

i'm working on ubuntu with vs code with dart but while runing i get this error " Set the 'program' value in your launch config (eg 'bin/main.dart') then launch again " and i have add in lanuch.json

> ```
> "program": "bin/main.dart",
> ```

and i get this error

> Error when reading 'bin/main.dart': No such file or directory.
> i have installed dart using this steps
> https://dart.dev/get-dart

Comment: Make sure the appropriate configuration is selected in the Run and Debug dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter extension for VSCode does not support Virtual Workspace right now. That's why you are not able to use Virtual Workspace with flutter.

As soon as you open Virtual Workspace the Flutter extension get disabled

[Screenshot of Flutter extension disabled in Virtual Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiuQ8.png)

Comment: I can't see how this could be related to the question and why it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @David You may have trouble understanding it because it belongs to the past and is no longer familiar or relevant to the present.

Answer (score 21):

Ok, so I was struggling with this as well and I felt like previous answers while correct, they don't address the issue for beginners. The issue seems to be that VS Code wants to know which is the file that it needs to debug, so if you type in the relative path to your file it will work right away.

In my case my file was named `helloWorld.dart`, so I had to specify that in the launch.json file.

it ended up looking like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart & Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
            "program": "helloWorld.dart",
        }
    ]
}
```

I advise using the full path to prevent issues that could arise from a different folder structure.

I guess the reason VS Code ask for `bin/main.dart` is because you are supposed to create that folder structure and `main.dart`is the most common/default file name.

Comment: For flutter... this scenario happened to me because I replaced main.dart with main_debug.dart, main_staging.dart & main_production.dart. To resolve this I created 3 launch profiles with the "program" attribute set to each of these files respectively

Answer (score 2):

**1st way**

try removing the first line containing configuration `Version`, now VS Code should not give you an error

Sample config after changes

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Flutter (lib/main.dart)",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    }
]
}
```

**2nd way**

1. save your existing launch config file (.vscode/launch.json) somewhere
2. Open VS Code
3. In the Explorer tab, right-click on the `main.dart` file and click `Create launch configuration`
4. Compare your previously saved config file with the newly created one and change the new config if necessary.
5. Try running your project

Answer (score 1):

Use below for vscode launch.json. Note that `"program": "testfiles/test.dart"` is the part to your file to debug.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Dart & Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "testfiles/test.dart"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I Have also got the same error while installing Dart Showing **"program": "bin/main.dart"** because I did not set the enviroment variable.
Try to Set Enviroment Variable For Dart

**C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin**

Try This it may Help

Answer (score 0):

Give the file name where the main() function , (where to start the program), we can see the name in tab , or left side , example myapp.dart , one.dart what name we gave to the file

or Second option
To run , click run|debug option top of void main() -main function, then no need to configure program: value.

Answer (score 0):

One other reason for this error is if we move the 'main.dart' from the lib folder to any other folders (or subfolders of lib). Moving 'main.dart' to the direct child in the lib file would solve this.